# Rotating a view in openGLES android

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am new to openGlEs in android. I tried out the tutorial mentioned here http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html

I am trying to rotate the square I have drawn. But noting happens. Here is my code snippet

```
@Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
    { 
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, 45, 0, 0, 1.0f);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);

        square.draw(mMVPMatrix);
    }
```

I can draw a square even without Matrix.methods . I am not sure what is happening here. Please suggest me a solution. It would be very helpful if anyone share links regarding this

Answer (score 0):

Put Matrix.setIdentityM(mRotationMatrix, 0); before setting rotation.